# Get text coordinates using wand and caption

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

Using wand, I've added text to an image using Image.caption(), and now I'm trying to figure out the size of the text box so I can draw a square behind the text.

I've looked the at the source and I see caption creates a new a image and then composites that image with the original.

```
with Color('transparent') as background_color:
            library.MagickSetBackgroundColor(textboard.wand,
                                             background_color.resource)
        textboard.read(filename=b'caption:' + text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Is there anyway to get the text metrics from that textboard Image object?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there's a [`wand.drawing.Drawing.get_font_metrics`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.Drawing.get_font_metrics) that will return a named-tuple [`wand.drawing.FontMetrics`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.FontMetrics).

... so I imagine you would do something like ...

```py
with Drawing() as context:
    metics = context.get_font_metrics(textboard,
                                     text,
                                     "\n" in text)
    # Use `text_height` & `text_width` values from metics.
```

I would also recommend using [`wand.drawing.Drawing.text`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.Drawing.text) over `caption:` protocol. Seems like more work, but will give your application more control.